# Matching extensions with only numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have a long list of file names in Python and I'm trying to use `re.match` to match them.

The extensions look like `.2` or `.33`, but the list also contains extensions like `.2base`, `.33z`, `.z5`. I don't want to match any extensions containing words and the first character needs to be a digit.

I've tried `re.match('\.\d^[a-z]', ext)` but that didn't work. `'\.\d'` returns most of the list, but it also returns `.2base` which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match a dot followed by 1+ digits and assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char `(?!\S)` using a negative lookahead:

```
\.\d+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rOGAEf/1)

If the filename is at the end of the string, you might also use:

```
\.\d+\Z
```

Instead of using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) which would start at the beginning of the string, you could use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

For example:

```
import re

pattern = r"\.\d+(?!\S)"
str = "filename.33"
str2 = "filename.2base"

print(re.match(pattern, str))
print(re.search(pattern, str))
print(re.match(pattern, str2))
print(re.search(pattern, str2))
```

Result

```
None
<re.Match object; span=(8, 11), match='.33'>
None
None
```

Comment: Wasn't `.33z` an extension they wanted to match?